# Prevent Excel Users From Changing Worksheet Name and Worksheet Order

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to prevent excel users from changing the worksheet name and worksheet order while preserving the filename as .xls or .xlsx instead of having to change it to .xlsm?

Please advise.

Comment: Yes; protect the workbook to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in my comment, you can protect the workbook to achieve this.

You can then password protect the workbook to completely prevent changes, or leave the password blank to simply "remind" users of the constraint.

In the dialog box that comes up, select the **structure** check box.